# How do I configure backspace behaviour in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to Visual Studio and C# development and one thing annoys me a bit. In IntelliJ/Android Studio pressing backspace in this situation:
code editor in VS

[image: code editor in VS]

would take me to the previous line (line 30) to exactly same position within the line - where the indented text starts. However, in Visual Studio pressing backspace in this situation will take me one character to the left, and then another one, and I have to keep pressing backspace all the way to the beginning of the line in order to go back to the previous one.

Is there a way to configure that so I only have to press backspace once to start typing in the line above? Thank you and sorry if the question is a bit silly but I've searched settings in VS and web and couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Or you could press "up". Since you want to go up.

Comment: that's true, but it's not going to remove the line I've just went up from @JeroenMostert

Comment: Shift-Up, then Delete. If two keystrokes are too inconvenient, you could have a mini-macro (but not in VS itself, since it dropped native support for macros way back when).

Comment: @Jacas For me, however, it is annoying, that pressing backspace at the beginning of an indented line takes me back to the *end* of the previous line :) I'd prefer the behaviour as you described it. Did you eventually find the settings to change the backspace behaviour ?

Comment: @Hermann Old thread, but figure I'd put this here for posterity: This may be resulting from a ReSharper setting.  In the ReSharper options, under `Editor` -> `Editor Behavior` is an option **Unindent on Backspace**.  I believe it defaults to the setting "To proper indent position".  Setting it to "Disabled" returns the behavior you described.

Answer (score 0):

The closest option I have found its: ctrl + backspace and then just backspace.
Visual Studio 2017